# A VoIP home phone that enables free unlimited calling

Tags: telephony, voip

When the Voice over IP (VoIP) company Ooma started, it sold a VoIP home phone that enabled free unlimited calling.  But as it grew, it started charging a variety of monthly fees and taxes, although it grandfathered in people who bought the original product.

My question is, are there any VoIP home phones that really do what Ooma started off doing, i.e. enable free unlimited calling with absolutely no monthly or annual fees or taxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a product that does what I want, the [OBi200](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BUV7C9A).  It's $50, and it's not a phone, you still need to buy a home phone separately and plug it into it.  But you don't need to get a paid VOIP or SIP service at all.  All you need is Google Voice, which is free.  This solution allows you to make and receive unlimited domestic calls within the US for free.  (EDIT: You can also use it if you’re outside the US and want to make free calls to the US.)

Note that the set up is pretty straightforward, but one problem I ran into is that I couldn't receive calls at first. It turns out way to solve that problem is to go into Google Voice settings, and under "Forward calls to", select "Google Chat".

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of Linksys devices that enables SIP-calling from normal analog phones. There's numerous software that supports these protocols, so you can easily combine it with a tablet, PC, smart phone, etc.

Of course, you'll still need the SIP VoIP provider, but the devices works well and they're quite cheap. I found several on Ebay: http://www.ebay.com/sch/Linksys-VoIP-Home-Phone-Adapters/99269/bn_354182/i.html

I have the SPA2102, which has two phone ports. I've been very happy with it. I also have two single-port ones, but I don't remember what they're named.

Comment: That's not what I want, I want something that allows you to pay $0 a month.

Comment: That's up to the service provider. I've been using these devices at $0 for years, using several different providers.

Comment: Oh ok.  Can you tell me some providers that charge $0 a month?

Comment: Well, no, I don't even know which countries you're interested in. Free calling sounds like bad business though, so I don't think there's many without some catch or other. What's more usual is that there's no subscription, but that you pay small rates for calls to phone numbers. Of couse, if you're only interested in calling from one internet user to another, then that's obviously free of charge.

Comment: I live in America, and I'm primarily interested in domestic calling.  Are you aware of any service providers that charge $0 per month and $0 for any domestic calls?

Comment: No, I'm Norwegian. :)

Comment: I finally found a solution that allows free unlimited calling with no monthly fees or any other kinds of fees.  See my answer.